# How to pass the background color of the clicked item in the RecyclerView to the Layout of the next activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with multiple background colors of items.
I want that when i clicked an item in my recyclerView the Layout of the next activity will have the same background color of the clicked item. How can i do this in my setOnClickListener method ? thanks

This is my adapter:

```
    public class AdapterColors extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterColors.MyViewholder> {

        List<Colors> listArray;
        Context context;

        public AdapterColors(List<Color> List,Context context){
        this.listArray = List;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext ()).inflate ( R.layout.itemview,parent,false );
        return new MyViewholder(view);
    }
        }
        @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewholder holder, int position) {

                Color data = listArray.get ( position );

                if(position % 5 == 0){
                    holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color1));
                }else if(position % 5 == 1){
                    holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color2));
                }else if(position % 5 == 2){
                    holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color3));
                }else if(position % 5 == 3){
                    holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color4));
                }else if(position % 5 == 4){
                    holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color5));
                }

                holder.TextColor.setText ( data.getColor ( ) );
            }
    }
```

Comment: you can pass your activity to the AdapterColors constructor. or simple set a listener and listen to it from your activity. Tell if I'm not making sense, so I try to present you with some code

Comment: pass the color to next activity and set on that that layout.

Comment: @ Reza Bigdeli : It will be better if you present me some code because i'm blocked in  " How can i do this in my setOnClickListener method ? " Thanks.

Comment: @ Praveen Rawat: I'm blocked in how can i pass the color to the next activity

Answer (score 0):

Pass color code via intent and next activity get value via getIntent().getStringExtra() then set backgroud color with parent view with .setBackgroudColor(Color.parse(getIntntStringExtra())).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
Drawable background = view.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
  color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();

//While passing in intent
intent.putExtra("backgroundColor",color);
```

Replace your "view" with your own view (recycler view parent item : ex Linear or Relative Layout )

Hope this helps !

Comment: this code is ok when i have an exact color but i would know how can i extract the backgroundColor of the clicked item and then pass it in an intent

Comment: Inside the onClick  method of recycler view item !

Answer (score 0):

Change your onBindViewHolder method code like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewholder holder, int position) {

        Color data = listArray.get ( position );

        if(position % 5 == 0){
            holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color1));
    holder.TextColor.setOnClickListener( View.OnCLickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("color_code", 0);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            // Enter the Above code in all the below cases as well

        }
    }
        }else if(position % 5 == 1){
            holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color2));
        }else if(position % 5 == 2){
            holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color3));
        }else if(position % 5 == 3){
            holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color4));
        }else if(position % 5 == 4){
            holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color5));
        }

        holder.TextColor.setText ( data.getColor ( ) );
    }
```

The in Next opening activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        switch(bundle.getString("color_code")) {
            case 0:
                // Your code logic
                break;
            case 1:
                // Your code logic
                break;
            case 2:
                // Your code logic
                break;
            case 3:
                // Your code logic
                break;
            case 4:
                // Your code logic
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach which is ideal

```
public class AdapterColors extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterColors.MyViewholder> {

    List<Color> listArray;
    Context context;
    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;


    public AdapterColors(List<Color> List,OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.listArray = List;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Color colors);
    }
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewholder holder, int position) {

            Color data = listArray.get ( position );

            if(position % 5 == 0){
                holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color1));
            }else if(position % 5 == 1){
                holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color2));
            }else if(position % 5 == 2){
                holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color3));
            }else if(position % 5 == 3){
                holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color4));
            }else if(position % 5 == 4){
                holder.TextColor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color5));
            }

            holder.TextColor.setText ( data.getColor ( ) );

        holder.TextColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(data);

            }
        });
        }
}
```

In your Activity Class

```
AdapterColors adapterColors = new AdapterColors(yourColorList,new AdapterColors.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Color color) {
        //Add your Activity code here
        // Add color in your bundle
    }
});
```